# Selecting All Select Boxes (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, select

I have a web page in which I need to add up each selection. So for example if someone selects A, then it will add 90 to the final value. At the moment I've done it manually by adding each ID of each select box (see code below), but now I've got so many select boxes that I think I need a better method! Thanks In Advance!

A Snippet of Code I currently have (theory1 being the ID of the select box):

```
var t1 = document.getElementById('theory1');
var tnum1 = 0;

        if(t1.options[t1.selectedIndex].value == "Grade 6 - Distinction"){
        tnum1 = tnum1+15;
        }

        if(t1.options[t1.selectedIndex].value == "Grade 6 - Merit"){
        tnum1 =tnum1+10;
        }

        if(t1.options[t1.selectedIndex].value == "Grade 6 - Pass"){
        tnum1 = tnum1+5;
        } document.getElementById('add').innerHTML = tnum1;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can give the options' value to be the value you want to add.

```
<select id="theory1">
  <option value="15">Grade 6 - Distinction</option>
  ...
</select>
```

then loop through the selects and add up the values

```
var selects = document.getElementsByTagName('select');
var tnum1 = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < selects.length; i++){
    tnum1 += +selects[i].value;
}
document.getElementById('add').innerHTML = tnum1;
```

Comment: Thanks! Easiest solution and cut down my code by about 1000 lines ha!

Answer (score 0):

You should use a dictionary for this solution

```
var action;
action["Grade 6 - Distinction"] = 15;
action["Grade 6 - Merit"] = 10;
action["Grade 6 - Pass"] = 5;

var selectedValue = t1.options[t1.selectedIndex].value;
tnum1 = tnum1 + action[selectedValue];
document.getElementById('add').innerHTML = tnum1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at jQuery or something similar. It allows you to easily iterate over all elements in a document with particular class, which would be probably what you want. (You will also need a way to map from values to numbers; encode it as a single function, eg.)